# Exposing swift structs to ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, struct

As I understand there is no way to use a **Swift** struct in **Objective-c** code.  Is there a best practice way to "wrap" a swift struct into an objective C class so that I can use the struct in my new code but keep a similar data structure in legacy code?

The best I can come up with is very code heavy - but it would be to make a protocol, and then implement a struct that uses that protocol for swift, and then an objective C class that has an internal member of the struct and exposes methods that dive into it.

```
protocol ParsedMessageProtocol {
    var timeStamp : NSDate { get }
    var msgData : NSData? { get }
    var source : String { get }

    init(data : NSData)
    init(rawData data : NSData, dataSource : String)
    init(date : NSDate)
}

@objc(DMParsedMessage)
class ParsedMessageClass : NSObject, ParsedMessageProtocol {

    private var swiftData : ParsedMessageStruct;

    required init(data : NSData) {
        self.swiftData = ParsedMessageStruct(data: data);
    }
    required init(date : NSDate) {
        self.swiftData = ParsedMessageStruct(date: date);
    }

    required init(rawData data : NSData, dataSource : String) {
        self.swiftData = ParsedMessageStruct(rawData: data, dataSource: dataSource)
    }

    var timeStamp : NSDate {
        return self.swiftData.timeStamp
    }

    var msgData : NSData? {
        return self.swiftData.msgData
    }

    var source : String {
        return self.swiftData.source
    }


}

struct ParsedMessageStruct : ParsedMessageProtocol {
    let timeStamp : NSDate
    let msgData : NSData?
    let source : String

    init(data : NSData) {
        timeStamp = NSDate()
        self.msgData = data;
        self.source = "UNSET";
    }
    init(rawData data : NSData, dataSource : String) {
        timeStamp = NSDate()
        self.msgData = data;
        self.source = dataSource;
    }
    init(date : NSDate) {
        timeStamp = date
        self.source = "UNSET";
        self.msgData = nil;
    }
}
```

I haven't had a chance to test if this will actually work in **Objective-C** but is this a reasonable approach, and if not - is there a less boiler plate version somebody can offer?